# For $3x^3-5x^2+12x-18=0$ find the value of $(1+\frac{x_1}{x_2})(1+\frac{x_2}{x_3})(1+\frac{x_3}{x_1})$ using Vieta's formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> For $3x^3-5x^2+12x-18=0$ find the value of $(1+\frac{x_1}{x_2})(1+\frac{x_2}{x_3})(1+\frac{x_3}{x_1})$ using Vieta's formulas.

I transformed it into $\dfrac{(x_2+x_1)(x_3+x_2)(x_1+x_3)}{x_1x_2x_3}$ , now I know the denominator equals $6$ but I'm stuck on the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum \alpha^2 \beta =(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)( \alpha \beta+\beta \gamma+ \gamma \alpha)-3 \alpha \beta \gamma.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

Hint:   let $s=x_1+x_2+x_3=\dfrac{5}{3}$, then (with $P(x)$ being the original cubic):

$$(x_2+x_1)(x_3+x_2)(x_1+x_3)=(s-x_1)(s-x_2)(s-x_3)=\frac{1}{3}P(s)=\frac{1}{3}P\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the second and third terms of the equation first $(1+\frac{x_1}{x_2})(1+\frac{x_2}{x_3})(1+\frac{x_3}{x_1})$:

$$\biggl(1+\frac{x_1}{x_2}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{x_1x_3+x_1x_2+x_2x_3}{x_3x_1}+\frac{x_3}{x_1} \biggr)$$
$$\biggl(1+\frac{x_1}{x_2}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{\frac ca}{x_3x_1}+\frac{x_3}{x_1} \biggr)$$
Then distribute the first term with the second term, and knowing where $x_3x_2+x_3x_1=\frac ca-x_1x_2$:
$$\biggl(\frac{x_2+x_1}{x_2}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{\frac ca}{x_3x_1}\biggr)+\biggl(\frac{x_2+x_1}{x_2}\biggr)\cdot\frac{x_3}{x_1} $$
$$\frac{\frac ca\cdot(x_2+x_1)}{x_1x_2x_3}+\frac{x_3x_2+x_3x_1}{x_2x_1}$$

$$\frac{c(x_2+x_1)}{a(x_1x_2x_3)}+\frac{\frac ca-x_1x_2}{x_1x_2}$$ Which can be simplified to:
$$\frac{c(x_2+x_1)}{a(x_1x_2x_3)}+\frac{c}{a}\cdot\frac1{x_1x_2}-1$$
$$\frac ca\biggl(\frac{x_1x_2^2+x_1^2x_2+x_1x_2x_3}{x_1^2x_2^2x_3}\biggr)-1$$
$$\frac ca\biggl(\frac1{x_1x_3}+\frac1{x_2x_3}+\frac1{x_1x_2}\biggr)-1$$
$$\frac ca\biggl(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{x_1x_2x_3}\biggr)-1$$
$$\frac ca\cdot\biggl(\frac{-b}c\biggr)-1=\frac{-b}a-1$$
$$\therefore (1+\frac{x_1}{x_2})(1+\frac{x_2}{x_3})(1+\frac{x_3}{x_1})=\frac53-1=\frac23$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Vieta's Theorem for cubic equations says: a cubic equation $x^3 + px^2 + qx + r = 0$ has three different roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
-p &=& x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
q &=& x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3 \\
-r &=& x_1x_2x_3
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$-5=x_1-x_2-x_3$$
$$12=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3$$
$$-18=-x_1x_2x_3$$

Answer (score 0):

One has

$$\begin{align}
(x_1+x_2)(x_2+x_3)(x_1+x_3)
&=(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2^2+x_2x_3)(x_1+x_3)\\
&=x_1^2x_2+x_1x_2x_3+x_1^2x_3+x_1x_3^2+x_1x_2^2+x_2^2x_3+x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3^2\\
&=x_1x_2(x_1+x_2+x_3)+x_1x_3(x_1+x_2+x_3)+x_2x_3(x_1+x_2+x_3)-x_1x_2x_3\\
&=(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)-x_1x_2x_3\end{align}$$